# Sending email after authentication in Outlook 2010

Tags: c#, email, outlook

I'm trying to send an email programmatically using outlook from a console application.

Here's my code:

```
        Outlook.Application app = new Outlook.Application();
        Outlook.MailItem mailItem = app.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);

         Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.NameSpace oNamespace = app.GetNamespace("MAPI");
        Outlook.MAPIFolder folder = oNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
        mailItem.Subject = "Mail sent " + DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString();
        mailItem.To = "email@example.com";//I'm using a real e-mail here

        //this is copied from the msdn, it scans the available Account object 
        //in outlook and return the one with the specified email address
        Outlook.Account account = GetAccountForEmailAddress(app, "myemail@example.com");

        mailItem.SendUsingAccount = account;

        string message = "test mail";

        mailItem.HTMLBody = message;
        mailItem.Display(true);

        //again copied from the msdn, casts the send method to avoid errors
        ((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._MailItem)mailItem).Send();
```

The emails are sent, but not received, and I get a report mail on my sending account with this (translated!) message

```
Can't reach the following address(es)

  'email@example.com' 03/08/2014 17:48
        server error: "530 Authentication required"
```

I wanted to use `Outlook.Application` instead of `SmtpClient` because this program must be runned from many computers using their credentials, and it seemed to me the best way using their account from Outlook.

Comment: Can you send messages through that account manually in Outlook?

Comment: Also note that you call MailItem.Display to display the message modally. If the user already clicked the Send button to send the message, you will call MailItem.Send again.